# Remove bottom border of MaterialBanner

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using MaterialBanner in Flutter. The problem is I cannot remove bottom border and could not find any border-related of MaterialBanner class.

flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner.dart

Here is my sample code.

```dart
Container(
  height: 130.0
  child: MaterialBanner(
    content: Text(
      'Text Text Text Text',
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      maxLines: 2,
    ),
    leading: Image.asset('images/xxx.png'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    forceActionsBelow: true,
    actions: <Widget>[
      InkWell(
        child: Container(child: Text('Button Text')),
        onTap: () {
          print('test');
        },
      ),
    ],
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: I find there's Divider used in Material Class. I guess I should create a layout without MaterialBanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add decoration to the Container with a border-color transparent

see below:

```
 Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent)),
      child: MaterialBanner(
         ......
       ),
     );
```

Comment: actually, I copy your code and run on **dartpad.dev** online with changes as I posted above and it works...

Comment: Oh I see. I think the problem lies outside of this code. Your answer works for my question then, I make it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: This approach can't be used with ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showMaterialBanner.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter in MaterialBanner to control this "border" color, you can just set it to transparent to make it disappear:

```
  MaterialBanner(
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
```